# .net mvc 2 validation: summing up values of several attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

I am using .NET 4 MVC 2 in my project. I basically have two classes, which I use for my validation. Class A is my (main) model, class B is an composite attribute which class A may have. The code looks like the following:

```
[Bind(Exclude = "A_ID")]
    public class A_Validation
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "something is missing")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        // some more attributes ...

        public B b { get; set; }
    }
```

All my validation based on class A is working very well. But now I want to validate the composite attribute B, which looks like the following.

```
[Bind(Exclude = "B_ID")]
    public class B_Validation
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "missing")]
        [Range(1, 210, ErrorMessage = "range between 1 and 210")]
        public int first { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "missing")]
        [Range(1, 210, ErrorMessage = "range between 1 and 210")]
        public int second { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "missing")]
        [Range(1, 210, ErrorMessage = "range between 1 and 210")]
        public int third { get; set; }
    }
```

**I am able to check the ranges** of B's three attributes *first*,*second* and *third*. **What I additionally want is to check if the *sum* of all three attributes** *first*,*second* and *third* **is below a certain threshold.**

Any ideas how to proceed?

*I think ViewModels might help, but i have no experience in using them.*

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried writing a custom validation attribute:

```
public class SumBelowAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _max;
    public SumBelowAttribute(int max)
    {
        _max = max;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var b = value as B_Validation;
        if (b != null)
        {
            return b.first + b.second + b.third < _max;
        }
        return base.IsValid(value);
    }
}
```

and then decorate the `B` property with this attribute:

```
[SumBelow(123)]
public B b { get; set; }
```

Comment: @Darin I've done this, but how should the view be able to show this validation result? _first_, _second_ and _third_ are all attributes which I can validate by using `<%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.B.first)%>` - how should I proceed with the sum?

Comment: @Jaques le Fraque, because this attribute applies to many properties you no longer use ValidationMessageFor to display error messages. You could display it using the `ValidationSummary` helper.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, the `ErrorMessage` I provided via `[SumBelow(123, ErrorMessage = "sum below 123")]` isn't shown in the `ValidationSummary`. Anyway, I also tried adding a clientside validation, which is not triggered at all

Comment: @Jaques le Fraque, have you tried like this `@Html.ValidationSummary(false)`? As far as client side validation is concerned this you will need to write a custom adapter for the jquery validate plugin.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, yes, I did the exact thing but this validation result is still missing :/

Comment: @Jaques le Fraque, is the `IsValid` method hit?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, no, I also provided an test-wise `alert()` in my clientside validation script, but nothing is invoked... (I implemented four other custom validation, which all work)